# Minimal C++ OpenGL Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault, glfw, glew

I am following the first instalment in [Tom Dalling's Modern OpenGL tutorial](http://www.tomdalling.com/blog/category/modern-opengl/) and when I downloaded his code it worked perfectly. So then I wanted to create my own minimal version to help me understand how it all worked.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GLM/glm.hpp>

#include <stdexcept>

GLFWwindow* gWindow = NULL;

GLint gProgram = 0;

GLuint gVertexShader = 0;
GLuint gFragmentShader = 0;

GLuint gVAO = 0;
GLuint gVBO = 0;

int main() {
    /** Initialise GLFW **/
    if (!glfwInit()){
        throw std::runtime_error("GLFW not initialised.");
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    gWindow = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL 3.2", NULL, NULL);
    if(!gWindow) {
        throw std::runtime_error("glfwCreateWindow failed.");
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(gWindow);

    /** Initialise GLEW **/
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Glew not initialised.");
    }
    if (!GLEW_VERSION_3_2) {
        throw std::runtime_error("OpenGL 3.2 not supported.");
    }

    /** Set up shaders **/
    gVertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); //Segmentation fault here
    gFragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(gVertexShader, 1, (const GLchar* const*)R"(
        #version 150

        in vec3 vertexPos

        out vec colour;

        void main() {
            colour = vertexPos;
            gl_Position = vec4(vertexPos, 1);
        }
        )", NULL);
    glShaderSource(gFragmentShader, 1, (const GLchar* const*)R"(
        #version 150

        in vec3 colour;

        out vec4 fragColour;

        void main() {
            fragColour = colour;
        }
        )", NULL);

    glCompileShader(gVertexShader);
    glCompileShader(gFragmentShader);

    /** Set up program **/
    gProgram = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(gProgram, gVertexShader);
    glAttachShader(gProgram, gFragmentShader);

    glLinkProgram(gProgram);

    glDetachShader(gProgram, gVertexShader);
    glDetachShader(gProgram, gFragmentShader);

    glDeleteShader(gVertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(gFragmentShader);

    /** Set up VAO and VBO **/
    float vertexData[] = {
        // X,    Y,    Z
        0.2f, 0.2f, 0.0f,
        0.8f, 0.2f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.8f, 0.0f,
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &gVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(gVAO);

    glGenBuffers(1, &gVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GL_FLOAT)*9, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(glGetAttribLocation(gProgram, "vertexPos"), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    /** Main Loop **/
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(gWindow)) {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gVBO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 1);
        glfwSwapBuffers(gWindow);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is what I created and it builds correctly. However when running it I get a segmentation fault upon calling glCreateShader.

I have done a lot of searching to find a solution to this and so far I've found two main reasons for this happening:

- One is that glewExperimental needs to be set to GL_TRUE, however nothing changed after adding this line.
- The second reason was that the OpenGL context was not being set, but I believe the call to glfwMakeContextCurrent covers this point.

From here I have no clue as of what to do, so any tips would be a great help!

EDIT: Thank you all for your help! I eventually managed to get it working and have uploaded the code to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0ELBSdvm) for future reference.

Comment: On what system do you try to compile and run your code?

Comment: I am using Windows 10, in Code::Blocks 16.01

Comment: Could you check if you can call `char *version = (char *)glGetString(GL_VERSION)` right before the `glCreateShader` and what the content of `version` is?

Comment: `version` is `4.5.0 NVIDIA 365.19`

Comment: Thats strange, IMHO there is nothing particular wrong. I would guess that GLEW did not set the function pointers and `glCreateShader` points to `0x0`. But I don't have a windows machine right here to test your code myself. The only difference I can see that I always used `GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE`  instead of `GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE`.

Comment: I tried changing to using `GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE` and no change. Also `std::cout << &glCreateShader` gives `0x6edcb7a4`

Comment: Sorry, i can't help you any further right now. Here the `glCreateShader` works fine. It only fails at `glShaderSource` because the way you pass the source is not valid.

Comment: try to change the order of libs in linker settings

Comment: Shader code is not valid. At least, you missed semicolon after the `in vec3 vertexPos` declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem solution

You program crashes not at the line you pointed, but on the first `glShaderSource` call. You actually pass a pointer to a string as the third argument, casting it to `(const GLchar* const*)`. That's not what `glShaderSource` expects. It rather expects a pointer to an array of pointers to strings, whose (array of pointer's) length should be passed as the second argument (see [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glShaderSource.xhtml)).

As a quick-n-dirty fix for your code, I declared the following:

```cpp
const char *vs_source[] = {
        "#version 150\n",
        "in vec3 vertexPos\n",
        "out vec colour;\n",
        "void main() {\n",
        "    colour = vertexPos;\n",
        "    gl_Position = vec4(vertexPos, 1);\n",
        "}\n"};

const char *fs_source[] = {
        "#version 150\n",
        "in vec3 colour;\n",
        "out vec4 fragColour;\n",
        "void main() {\n",
        "    fragColour = colour;\n",
        "}\n"};
```

and replaced the calls to `glShaderSource` to

```cpp
glShaderSource(gVertexShader, 7, (const char**)vs_source, NULL);
glShaderSource(gFragmentShader, 6, (const char**)fs_source, NULL);
```

Now the program works fine and shows a window as expected.

### Hints

- Your code did not even compile on my machine (I use gcc 4.8.3 @ Linux) because of cast of a string literal to `(const GLchar* const*)`. So try to set more restrictive flags in your compiler options and pay attention at compiler warnings. Moreover, treat warnings as errors.
- Use some kind of memory profiler to determine the exact location of crashes. For example, I used Valgrind to localize the problem.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, as I was very unsure about the weird typecasting I was doing before. However, I was expecting a triangle to be drawn in the window, not for it to just be black, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @AlexMorson Ah, yes, I didn't go deeply to the further code. Probably you have another subtle problem with pointers.

Comment: I managed to sort out all the problems, so I actually have a triangle! Thank you for your help @Sergey, and if anyone wants the final code I uploaded it to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0ELBSdvm)